# .NET Delete items in Icollection Before Deleting Entry

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Links is an icollection of identifiers and I want to delete an identifier but first I have to delete the entries in links however I get this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session.

I'm not sure how to get around this?

```
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var UserTableID = db.UserTables.Where(c => c.ApplicationUserId == userId).First().ID;
        Identifier identifier = db.Identifiers.Find(id);
        if (identifier.UserTableID == UserTableID)
        {
            foreach (var item in db.Links.Where(c => c.IdentifierID == identifier.ID))
            {
                db.Links.Remove(item);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            db.Identifiers.Remove(identifier);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

Comment: What line does this error occur on? Have you tried removing the `db.SaveChanges()` in the foreach and just let the final `db.SaveChanges()` handle the save?

Comment: @Michael_B this worked as well thanks! I didn't realise it could handle any db, I assumed it was only relevant to one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely caused by the `foreach` loop since you're actively pulling in data from the db while simultaneously trying to save it. Try adding a `.ToList()` to your `foreach` loop.

```
foreach (var item in (db.Links.Where(c => c.IdentifierID == identifier.ID)).ToList())
{
  db.Links.Remove(item);
  db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first, your foreach didn't has ToList, the query was not executed.

and , from your code, variable "db" must be singleton,
web is multi thread app, 
while two thread use "db" run task, you'll get unpredictable error.